# Diagonalization of complex matrix with symbols in sympy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I tried to diagonalize a complex matrix with symbols by sympy as follows;

```py
from sympy import *
a, b, c = symbols('a b c', real=True)
m = Matrix([[a, I * b], [-I * b, c]])
m.eigenvects()
```

The matrix is Hermitian so that it must be diagonalizable, but the last line fails with

```
NotInvertible: zero divisor
```

I checked the diagonalization succeed for matrices either without `sympy.I` or symbols. (As a workaround, it seems that using another non-real symbol, say `j`, instead of `sympy.I`, works.)
Is the diagonalization with an explicit `sympy.I` symbol is not supported or is something wrong in my code?

I am using sympy on jupyter with its latest official docker image (`jupyter/datascience-notebook`). The version of sympy is 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in sympy 1.8. It is already fixed for 1.9 which will be released soon. In fact you can install 1.9rc1 with `pip install --pre -U sympy`. Then you should see:

```
   ...: a, b, c = symbols('a b c', real=True)
   ...: m = Matrix([[a, I * b], [-I * b, c]])
   ...: m.eigenvects()
Out[1]: 
⎡⎛                                        ⎡⎡          ⎛           ________________________⎞⎤⎤⎞  ⎛  
⎢⎜           ________________________     ⎢⎢          ⎜          ╱  2              2    2 ⎟⎥⎥⎟  ⎜  
⎢⎜          ╱  2              2    2      ⎢⎢          ⎜a   c   ╲╱  a  - 2⋅a⋅c + 4⋅b  + c  ⎟⎥⎥⎟  ⎜  
⎢⎜a   c   ╲╱  a  - 2⋅a⋅c + 4⋅b  + c       ⎢⎢        ⅈ⋅⎜─ + ─ - ───────────────────────────⎟⎥⎥⎟  ⎜a 
⎢⎜─ + ─ - ───────────────────────────, 1, ⎢⎢  ⅈ⋅c     ⎝2   2                2             ⎠⎥⎥⎟, ⎜─ 
⎢⎜2   2                2                  ⎢⎢- ─── + ───────────────────────────────────────⎥⎥⎟  ⎜2 
⎢⎜                                        ⎢⎢   b                       b                   ⎥⎥⎟  ⎜  
⎢⎜                                        ⎢⎢                                               ⎥⎥⎟  ⎜  
⎣⎝                                        ⎣⎣                       1                       ⎦⎦⎠  ⎝  

                                      ⎡⎡          ⎛           ________________________⎞⎤⎤⎞⎤
         ________________________     ⎢⎢          ⎜          ╱  2              2    2 ⎟⎥⎥⎟⎥
        ╱  2              2    2      ⎢⎢          ⎜a   c   ╲╱  a  - 2⋅a⋅c + 4⋅b  + c  ⎟⎥⎥⎟⎥
  c   ╲╱  a  - 2⋅a⋅c + 4⋅b  + c       ⎢⎢        ⅈ⋅⎜─ + ─ + ───────────────────────────⎟⎥⎥⎟⎥
+ ─ + ───────────────────────────, 1, ⎢⎢  ⅈ⋅c     ⎝2   2                2             ⎠⎥⎥⎟⎥
  2                2                  ⎢⎢- ─── + ───────────────────────────────────────⎥⎥⎟⎥
                                      ⎢⎢   b                       b                   ⎥⎥⎟⎥
                                      ⎢⎢                                               ⎥⎥⎟⎥
                                      ⎣⎣                       1                       ⎦⎦⎠⎦
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what causes the bug? I cannot find seemingly related issue on github.

Comment: It was fixed here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/21134